# INDEPENDENT sprite movement in "x" and "y" in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, game-physics

Ok so here is my current program:

```
bif="bg.jpg"
mif="pkmn.png"


import pygame
import sys

from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen=pygame.display.set_mode ((600,375),0,32)
background=pygame.image.load(bif).convert()
mouse_c=pygame.image.load(mif).convert_alpha()

x,y=0,0
movex, movey=0,0

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type==KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_LEFT:
                movex=-1
            elif event.key==K_RIGHT:
                movex=+1
            elif event.key==K_UP:
                movey=-1
            elif event.key==K_DOWN:
                movey=+1

        if event.type==KEYUP:
            if event.key==K_LEFT:
                movex=0
            elif event.key==K_RIGHT:
                movex=0
            elif event.key==K_UP:
                movey=0
            elif event.key==K_DOWN:
                movey=0

    x+=movex
    y+=movey

    screen.blit(background,(0,0))
    screen.blit(mouse_c,(x,y))

    pygame.display.update()
```

The problem is, even tho I can move in all directions, when I press the right arrow key for example, it moves to the right, then if i keep holding right arrow key and hold down left arrow key, it will move left, the problem is this: when I let go of the right key, even tho I was going to the left, my sprite stops.

I know the problem is that when either right or left is released, x goes to 0

**I wanna be able to hold right and go right, then hold left and go left instead, but then release left and go right because I was holding right**

I hope I explained myself, I have tried everything and searched everywhere, please help me, if anyone can modify my code and just show it to me so i can analyze it, that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: It is certainly not possile wit events, since the only event that happened is the releasing of another key.

Comment: are you sure you don't want to stop moving when both left and right are pressed? That makes more sense to me

Comment: Actually "ahuff44" that sounds viable too.

Comment: I've updated my answer to make it do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pygame
import sys

from pygame.locals import *


bif="bg.jpg"
mif="pkmn.png"


pygame.init()
FPS = 30  # changed for FPS
FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()  # changed for FPS

screen = pygame.display.set_mode ((600,375),0,32)
background = pygame.image.load(bif).convert()
mouse_c = pygame.image.load(mif).convert_alpha()

move_speed = 5  # changed for FPS
x, y = 0, 0

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pressed[K_LEFT]:
        x -= move_speed
    if pressed[K_RIGHT]:
        x += move_speed
    if pressed[K_UP]:
        y -= move_speed
    if pressed[K_DOWN]:
        y += move_speed

    screen.blit(background,(0,0))
    screen.blit(mouse_c,(x,y))

    pygame.display.update()
    FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)  # changed for FPS
```

**Edit 1:** I was running your code and noticed that you don't have any FPS monitoring- you're just running the code at the maximum rate the CPU can handle it. That'll lead to problems later, so I added code to make sure your FPS never goes above 30.

**Edit 2:** My old code was way overcomplicated; now that you agree that holding left and right should do nothing; this will work. (and it will be much more readable too, which helps protect you from bugs)

Comment: Thanks so much for the FPS advice and code, i just learned a new thing :D, however, with this code it wont let my sprite go on diagonal, is there anything we can do to fix this?

Thanks for everything, I'm really thankful (:

Comment: yep, no problem! as I said in my edit, the stuff with the `stack` was way too complicated, so hopefully the way this works now is fine with you

Comment: Again, thanks so much, I'm just a beginner but I really want to make some quality indie games so your post was really useful, cant thumbs up your post cause i dont have enough rep

Comment: I'm happy to help! I just started with pygame recently too. And you might not be able to thumb up, but you should be able to mark my answer as "accepted" by clicking on the green checkmark outline under the number of votes next to the top of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your event loop, check the state of the keys with [pygame.key.get_pressed](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed):

```
    while True:
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        print(pressed[pygame.K_LEFT], pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT])
```

See [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11930034/190597), for example.