# How does this specific double for loop work in python? Explaining a double for loop

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to understand and apply this single-lined double for loop outside of pygame. 
The double for loop:

```
for m in (move_map[key] for key in move_map):
```

This is originally from a code that, id name: sloth, wrote on the page:

[Pygame: key.get_pressed() does not coincide with the event queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910410/pygame-key-get-pressed-does-not-coincide-with-the-event-queue)

```
#the list
move_map = {pygame.K_LEFT: pygame.Vector2(-1, 0),
            pygame.K_RIGHT: pygame.Vector2(1, 0),
            pygame.K_UP: pygame.Vector2(0, -1),
            pygame.K_DOWN: pygame.Vector2(0, 1)}

#in the game loop 
for m in (move_map[key] for key in move_map if pressed[key]):
```

I first did a print(m) to to understand the mechanics(which worked):

```
move_map = {pygame.K_LEFT: pygame.Vector2(-1, 0),
            pygame.K_RIGHT: pygame.Vector2(1, 0),
            pygame.K_UP: pygame.Vector2(0, -1),
            pygame.K_DOWN: pygame.Vector2(0, 1)}

for m in (move_map[key] for key in move_map):
    print(m)
```

I dumbed it down even more but didn't work:

```
move_map = {(-1, 0),
            (1, 0),
            (0, -1),
            (0, 1)}

for m in (move_map[key] for key in move_map):
    print(m)
```

Could someone give me an easy example of how to use this?

Comment: `I'm assuming Vector2 is ...` - you shouldn't assume, dig into the docs and find out what it is.

Comment: At the very least try what Python is telling you about it: `print (type(pygame.Vector2))`

Comment: @usr2564301  I did that but my goal is the cherry pick this out of pygame and use it for non-pygame usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is called list comprehension and you can read about it in the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), the idea is that it allows you to create a list with less syntax. More concisely you could look at [nested list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions)

To answer your question a simple example of how to use it would be:

```
words = "foo bar baz"
print([char for word in words.split() for char in word])
```

which ouputs:

```
['f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r', 'b', 'a', 'z']
```

And is equivalent to:

```
letters = []
for word in words.split():
    for char in word:
        letters.append(char)
print(letters)
```

The one that you mention is slightly more complicated because it introduces an if statement in the middle:

```
for m in (move_map[key] for key in move_map if pressed[key]):
    print(m)
```

Is equivalent to:

```
movements = []
for key in move_map:
    if pressed[key]:
        movements.append(move_map[key])
for m in movements:
    print(m)
```