# Pygame - 2 keys stops jet

Tags: python, pygame

Hello Guys I'm pretty new to python and programming in general. I started making my own game using pygame but I'm facing a problem. I'm creating the cliche game where a ship shoots a fleet of aliens.

I made my ship move but for example:

When I press the right key then the left key such that they are pressed at the same time, then release the right the ship stops, its due to the `pygame.keyup` causing the `increment = 0` when releasing the right key.
But idk how to fix it so that i can control the ship without stopping every now and then because of the fast switch between keys.

Im looking for a way when I press a key it disregards the keyup of the previous key but when I don't press any button the ship stops

My code:

```
import sys
import pygame

pygame.init()

# Setting up a window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,800))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()


# Caption
pygame.display.set_caption("space shooter".title())


# Setting up the icon
icon = pygame.image.load("undertake.png").convert_alpha()
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)


# Identifying a Background
bg = pygame.image.load("bg.png").convert_alpha()


# Adding the jet
jet = pygame.image.load("jet.png").convert_alpha()
jet_rect = jet.get_rect()
jet_rect.centerx = screen_rect.centerx
jet_rect.bottom = screen_rect.bottom
jet_xincrement=0


# Moving the jet
def move_jet(x):
    jet_rect.centerx += x


# Adding Boundaries
def boundaries():
    if jet_rect.left >= 1200:
        jet_rect.right = 0
    elif jet_rect.right <= 0:
        jet_rect.left = 1200


# Game Loop
while True:
    screen.blit(bg,(0,0))
    screen.blit(jet,jet_rect)

    # EVENTS
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # Quitting
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        # Key Strokes
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                jet_xincrement = 3
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                jet_xincrement = -3

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                jet_xincrement = 0


    boundaries()
    move_jet(jet_xincrement)



    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of listening for key events, just check the current state of the keys with `pygame.key.get_pressed()`.

Change your event loop to something like this.

```
    ...

    # EVENTS
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # Quitting
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    jet_xincrement = 0
    if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]: jet_xincrement += 3
    if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]: jet_xincrement -= 3

    boundaries()
    move_jet(jet_xincrement)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: OH MY GOD, I heard the python community was really supportive and I'm so happy to be part of it. I hope I can become an expert and help other people like you do! Thanks    
 a lot! YOU MADE MY DAY

Comment: @HamzaEyad No problem. For another example, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11930034/142637), which deals with the same topic.